# How to access elements of numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm using scipy's `loadmat` function to load a matlab data file into python.

```
from scipy.io import loadmat  

data   = loadmat('data.mat')
fields = data['field']
```

The type of `fields` is `numpy.ndarray`:

```
print 'fields type={}'.format(type(fields))
print 'fields dtype={}'.format(fields.dtype)
print 'fields shape={}'.format(fields.shape)
```

> ```
> fields type=<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
> fields dtype=object
> fields shape=(5,)
> ```

I iterate over the array using `nditer`:

```
for x in np.nditer(fields, flags=['refs_ok']):
    print 'x={}'.format(x)
    print 'x type={}'.format(type(x))
    print 'x dtype={}'.format(x.dtype)
    print 'x shape={}'.format(x.shape)
    break
```

> ```
> x=[u'ACE']
> x type=<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
> x dtype=object
> x shape=()
> ```

**IndexError:**

If I try to access the first element of `x` I get an `IndexError`:

```
x[0]
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-102-8c374ae22096> in <module>()
>      17     print 'type={}'.format(type(x))
>      18     print 'dtype={}'.format(x.dtype)
> ---> 19     x[0]
>      20     break
>      21 
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array
> ```

**Questions:**

- How come, if `type(x)` returns `nump.ndarray` it says "too many indices for array"?
- How can I extract the contents of `x` into a string?

**Here are the versions I'm using:**

```
print 'python version: {}'.format(sys.version)
print 'numpy version: {}'.format(numpy.__version__)
print 'scipy version: {}'.format(scipy.__version__)
```

> ```
> python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
> [GCC 4.8.2]
> numpy version: 1.11.0
> scipy version: 0.17.1
> ```

Comment: Can you print out `x.shape`?

Comment: @C_Z_ - updated the question to include `x.shape`, which returns `()`

Comment: That's a 0d array, which you must index with a 0 element tuple, `x[()]`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without looking at your errors in detail I can point out some pitfalls.

The .mat will contain MATLAB matrices (always 2d or higher), cells and structures.

`loadmat` renders those in various ways.  There are dictionaries that you have to index by name.  There are object arrays (dtype=object).  And there are nd numeric or string arrays.  You may have to work through several levels to get at the numeric array.

Check the 'shape' (size) of an array and its 'dtype'.  If shape is `()` and `dtype` object, then extract it with `y=x[()]`.

Here's an example of such a 0d object array:

```
In [4]: y=np.arange(3)

In [5]: x=np.empty((), dtype=object)    
In [6]: x[()]=y

In [7]: x
Out[7]: array(array([0, 1, 2]), dtype=object)

In [8]: x.shape
Out[8]: ()

In [9]: x.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('O')

In [10]: x[0]
...
IndexError: too many indices for array

In [11]: x[()]
Out[11]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

`x` is a 0d array (x.ndim), so it must be indexed with a 0 element tuple, `()`.  For a MATLAB programmer that can seem odd.

In `numpy` (Python in general), `x[a,b,c]` is the same as `x[(a,b,c)]` and `ind=(a,b,c); x[ind]`.  In other words, the arguments in `[]` are understood to be a tuple of values.  `(1,2)` is a 2 element tuple, `(1,)` is one element ( `(1)` is just a grouping), and `()` is a 0 element tuple.  So `x[()]` is just an extension of the regular `nd` indexing notation.  It isn't a special case.

Comment: Thank you, using that array indexing notation (`x[()]`) worked. Do you have a resource where I can read up on that notation? I've never seen that before.

Comment: I added a paragraph on this notation.

Comment: `x.item()` is another way of extracting this single item.