# .mat to python data transfer

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am somewhat new to the python environment and I am transferring an existing MATLAB program into Python. I have imported a .mat file containing four fields in which I am interested in one with 14 subfields of 11340x1, 11340x7, and 11340x8 arrays as well as a handful of strings of meteorological data. I have successfully imported the data using

```
import scipy.io as sio
import scipy

MATfile = sio.loadmat(E:/JP/Meadowdata.mat)
```

Now I would like to put these arrays/strings in variables to use in Python. I started by

```
datagroup = MATfile['MAIN'] #for MAIN field
T = datagroup['T'] #for Temp.
P = datagroup['P'] #for Precip....
```

and so on for the other arrays. I wish to use these arrays both for the values within them and to find the length of the arrays. However, when I try to find the length they always come back with a length of 1 rather than 11340 and when I print them it appears like this

```
 [[array([[-5.55555556],
   [-5.55555556],
   [-5.55555556],
   ..., 
   [ 9.879     ],
   [ 8.17      ],
   [ 6.051     ]])]]
```

I noticed some people looped through and pulled values that way but this would be too much data/time in my case and it didn't seem to be working anyway. Is there any way I can reach this data?

Thanks,
jmatt

Comment: What if you let `T = datagroup['T'][0][0]` and `P = datagroup['P'][0][0]` and then check their lengths?

Comment: What is the `.shape` and `.dtype` of these arrays?  `.shape` is the equivalent to `size`.  `numpy` arrays may be 0 dimensional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996883/how-to-access-elements-of-numpy-ndarray.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Have you tried the `squeeze_me` argument for `loadmat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `datagroup['T']` (and `datagroup['P']`) is a list of a list of a `numpy` array. Therefore, if you want to extract the `numpy` array, you need to do:

```
T = datagroup['T'][0][0]
P = datagroup['P'][0][0]
```

Comment: You may need to index with `[()]`.  Check the `shape` and `dtype`.  `loadmat` often embeds MATLAB structures in single element object dtype arrays.  These are 0d, so require this special indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different and sometimes more stable solution.

I have found that the best solution when moving data between Matlab/Python is to use a JSON export library in matlab (e.g. [this one](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files)), then use the JSON import library in python. I have found this is a bit more stable than scipy's .mat load function, especially if you plan on importing frequently or use any of the more Matlab-specific variable types such as structs.

Comment: What do MATLAB matrices transfer as?  Nested lists?

Comment: With Python's native json library, yes, nested lists. Numpy's `asarray()` will turn them into a multidimensional array quite easily though.

Answer (score 0):

I can make an array that prints like your example with:

```
In [1355]: A=np.array([[None]])   
In [1356]: A[0,0]=np.array([[-5,-4,-3]])

In [1357]: A
Out[1357]: array([[array([[-5, -4, -3]])]], dtype=object)

In [1359]: print(A)
[[array([[-5, -4, -3]])]]
```

It's a single element, 2d object array that contains a 2d numeric array.  There are several ways of extracting the inner array:

```
In [1360]: A.item()
Out[1360]: array([[-5, -4, -3]])

In [1362]: A[0,0]
Out[1362]: array([[-5, -4, -3]])

In [1363]: A[0][0]
Out[1363]: array([[-5, -4, -3]])
```

In other questions the outer array is 0d  [How to access elements of numpy ndarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996883/how-to-access-elements-of-numpy-ndarray)

```
In [1364]: B=np.array(None) 
In [1365]: B[()]=np.array([[1,2,3]])

In [1366]: B
Out[1366]: array(array([[1, 2, 3]]), dtype=object)

In [1367]: print(B)
[[1 2 3]]

In [1368]: B[()]
Out[1368]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [1369]: B.item()
Out[1369]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

`item` still works.

I'm not sure where the difference arises.  I don't have Octave running on this machine so can't test whether V number makes a difference.

This tutorial page

http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/scipy_doc/tutorial/io.html

is better than the `loadmat` reference page.

The questions to ask, at any level of extraction, are:

- what is it?  Dictionary, array
- if array, what is the dtype?  Object?  compound (structured), numeric
- what is its shape?  How many dimensions (ndim)?

Comment: Thanks everyone. That numpy extraction worked great.