# Object array to numpy array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I have a file,which is a dictionary containing multidimensional arrays,part of the file look like this

```
{'__globals__': [], 'ecgdata': array([[[  0.64927447,  -6.9518466 ,  -2.01598597, ...,   6.0144043 ,14.82659912,   9.60320473]],
       [[-10.91237354, -10.82145023,   5.33286715, ...,7.53680801,10.95550919,   7.91685963],[-15.30590725,   5.42344713, -13.84104443, ...,  10.68752861,7.95283413,   0.47035939]],[[-13.26809025, -11.63397312,  15.1417799 , ...,   4.38294888,9.83382416,   8.45503426],...,[-14.91312885,  11.75222111, -11.65044498, ...,   6.97022438,10.74245644,  -2.57275534]],..., [[-10.96194077,  -9.53885269,   5.87950087, ...,   5.83128738,5.32846308,  11.16324234],[-11.92566872,   8.81869507, -11.59397984, ...,   5.50253582,10.94230938,  -1.49227607]],[[ -5.74656582,   0.27805901,  -3.73075247, ...,   0.96725273,2.3064785 ,   4.91951847],[ -3.15279818,  -1.82596517,  -1.49705577, ...,   3.69363403,4.91635323,  -6.07875967]],[[ -9.50158024,   8.16193676,   4.33013773, ...,   6.0825882 ,-11.67652321,   1.97953737],[  5.58597708,   2.6614821 ,   2.63657999, ..., -19.56603241,-2.59806776,   0.98835891]]], dtype=float32)}
```

I want to convert this object array to numpy array,so I can be able to print the shape and know the dimension and the size of each dimension.I have tried to extract the items of the dictionary and convert to numpy array but I still have object when I check the data type of the output.Here are the codes am using now to convert the data to numpy array but still the output is object.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
data=scipy.io.loadmat('filename.mat')
X= np.asarray(data)
print(X.dtype)`
```

I have tried to check the shape of the object array,I get ().I believe this should be direct but I am a newbie,teaching myself python...any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What object array?

Comment: This isn't an object array. This is a dict. You only get an object array once you call `asarray` on your dict, an operation that doesn't make any sense. If you want to get the arrays out of this dict, index it.

Comment: I get the object after I convert to array with asarray but the original file is a dictionary as I said at the first line of my question@user2357112

Comment: Have you looked at `data`?  `loadmat` creates a dictionary containing header information, as well as the variables that you saved in MATLAB.  MATLAB matrices are loaded as `np.arrays` (order "F"), but cells and structs will have one or more layers of `object` dtype array wrapping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37997214/901925 demonstrates a loadmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have pointed out `data` is a dictionary. If you want to extract the 'ecgdata' part all you need to do is:

```
ecg_data = data['ecgdata']
```