# How to efficiently extract values from nested numpy arrays generated by loadmat function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nested-lists

Is there a more efficient method in python to extract data from a nested python list such as `A =  array([[array([[12000000]])]], dtype=object)`. I have been using `A[0][0][0][0]`, it does not seem to be an efficinet method when you have lots of data like A.

I have also used
`numpy.squeeeze(array([[array([[12000000]])]], dtype=object))` but this gives me

```
array(array([[12000000]]), dtype=object)
```

PS: The nested array was generated by  `loadmat()` function in scipy module to load a .mat file which consists of nested structures.

Comment: after `np.squeeze(np.array([[np.array([[12000000]])]], dtype=object))` I've got `array(12000000, dtype=object)`

Comment: that would still require me to use indexing right ?

Comment: nope, result is just numpy scalar, you can wrap it in `int()` if you want

Comment: Almost, use `np.squeeze(np.array([[np.array([[12000000]])]], dtype=object)).item()`

Comment: Just wondering is it output produced by loadmat function? I am getting similar result when I load .mat file using loadmat funciton .

Comment: @Spandy ya i loaded mat file using loadmat function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating such an array is a bit tedious, but `loadmat` does it to handle the MATLAB cells and 2d matrix:

```
In [5]: A = np.empty((1,1),object)
In [6]: A[0,0] = np.array([[1.23]])
In [7]: A
Out[7]: array([[array([[ 1.23]])]], dtype=object)
In [8]: A.any()
Out[8]: array([[ 1.23]])
In [9]: A.shape
Out[9]: (1, 1)
```

`squeeze` compresses the shape, but does not cross the `object` boundary

```
In [10]: np.squeeze(A)
Out[10]: array(array([[ 1.23]]), dtype=object)
```

but if you have one item in an array (regardless of shape) `item()` can extract it.  Indexing also works, `A[0,0]`

```
In [11]: np.squeeze(A).item()
Out[11]: array([[ 1.23]])
```

`item` again to extract the number from that inner array:

```
In [12]: np.squeeze(A).item().item()
Out[12]: 1.23
```

Or we don't even need the `squeeze`:

```
In [13]: A.item().item()
Out[13]: 1.23
```

`loadmat` has a `squeeze_me` parameter.

Indexing is just as easy:

```
In [17]: A[0,0]
Out[17]: array([[ 1.23]])
In [18]: A[0,0][0,0]
Out[18]: 1.23
```

`astype` can also work (though it can be picky about the number of dimensions).

```
In [21]: A.astype(float)
Out[21]: array([[ 1.23]])
```

With single item arrays like efficiency isn't much of an issue.  All these methods are quick.  Things become more complicated when the array has many items, or the items are themselves large.

[How to access elements of numpy ndarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37996883)

Comment: The mat file that I am loading is a matlab nested structure, I tried using squeeze_me = True , but that makes the object of type void

Answer (score 3):

You could use A.all() or A.any() to get a scalar. This would only work if A contains one element.

Answer (score 2):

Try `A.flatten()[0]`

This will flatten the array into a single dimension and extract the first item from it. In your case, the first item is the only item.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my case was the following..

```
import scipy.io

xcat = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(dir_data, file_name))
pars = xcat['pars']  # Extract numpy.void element from the loadmat object

# Note that you are dealing with a numpy structured array object when you enter pars[0][0]. 
# Thus you can acces names and all that...
dict_values = [x[0][0] for x in pars[0][0]]  # Extract all elements in one go
dict_keys = list(pars.dtype.names)  # Extract the corresponding names/tags
dict_xcat = dict(zip(dict_keys, dict_values))  # Pack it up again in a dict
```

where the idea behind this is.. first extract ALL values I want, and format them in a nice python dict.
This prevents me from cumbersome indexing later in the file...

Of course, this is a very specific solution. Since in my case the values I needed were all floats/ints.