# Why do I get a void numpy array when I try to load the EMNIST dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to load a database of handwritten letters into python from the [EMNIST database](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/emnist-dataset). I downloaded the matlab format files and got 6 .mat files. I put them in the same directory as my .py file and loaded them like this:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy

data = sio.loadmat("emnist-letters.mat")

print(type(data['dataset'][0,0]))
```

I get this as the output:

```
<class 'numpy.void'>
```

With shape (1,1)

When I check the keys on the dictionary that loadmat returned I get ['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'dataset'])

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html Docs mention only some version are supported. 7.3, for example, is not supported. What version are the .mats?

Comment: @Dylan I printed the '\__version__' key and they all said 1.0. I guess that would not be supported, right?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, since the Notes say "v4 (Level 1.0)..." which is rather confusing to me. if you just try and return "data['dataset']" without the print() and type() what happens?

Comment: @Dylan the program just terminates since I'm currently not returning it to anything

Comment: Look at the `dtype` of an array rather than the `type`.  `data` is a dictionary.  `data['dataset']` is an array.  But depending on what MATLAB object was stored it might be a object dtype array, or something more complicated.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996883/how-to-access-elements-of-numpy-ndarray for more details.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah thank you, if I replace `type` with `numpy.dtype` I get: `[('train', 'O'), ('test', 'O'), ('mapping', 'O')]`. I needed to add another index to get what I wanted ([0][0][0] worked).

Comment: That's a structured array with 3 fields, possibly a `struct` in the original MATLAB.  I'd try to access elements with `data['dataset']['train']` or `data['dataset'][0,0]['test']`.  But the elements themselves might be arrays (the 'O' object dtype).

Comment: @hpaulj Cool, thanks a lot!